# 'Stable' multi-dimensional scaling algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a wireless mesh network of nodes, each of which is capable of reporting its 'distance' to its neighbors, measured in (simplified) signal strength to them. The nodes are geographically in 3d space but because of radio interference, the distance between nodes need not be trigonometrically (trigonomically?) consistent. I.e., given nodes A, B and C, the distance between A and B might be 10, between A and C also 10, yet between B and C 100.

What I want to do is visualize the logical network layout in terms of connectness of nodes, i.e. include the logical distance between nodes in the visual.

So far my research has shown the multidimensional scaling (MDS) is designed for exactly this sort of thing. Given that my data can be directly expressed as a 2d distance matrix, it's even a simpler form of the more general MDS.

Now, there seem to be many MDS algorithms, see e.g. http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/Matlab_Toolbox_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.html and http://tapkee.lisitsyn.me/ . I need to do this in C++ and I'm hoping I can use a ready-made component, i.e. not have to re-implement an algo from a paper. So, I thought this: https://sites.google.com/site/simpmatrix/ would be the ticket. And it works, but:

- The layout is not stable, i.e. every time the algorithm is re-run, the position of the nodes changes (see differences between image 1 and 2 below - this is from having been run twice, without any further changes). This is due to the initialization matrix (which contains the initial location of each node, which the algorithm then iteratively corrects) that is passed to this algorithm - I pass an empty one and then the implementation derives a random one. In general, the layout does approach the layout I expected from the given input data. Furthermore, between different runs, the direction of nodes (clockwise or counterclockwise) can change. See image 3 below.
- The 'solution' I thought was obvious, was to pass a stable default initialization matrix. But when I put all nodes initially in the same place, they're not moved at all; when I put them on one axis (node 0 at 0,0 ; node 1 at 1,0 ; node 2 at 2,0 etc.), they are moved along that axis only. (see image 4 below). The relative distances between them are OK, though.

So it seems like this algorithm only changes distance between nodes, but doesn't change their location.

Thanks for reading this far - my questions are (I'd be happy to get just one or a few of them answered as each of them might give me a clue as to what direction to continue in):

- Where can I find more information on the properties of each of the many MDS algorithms?
- Is there an algorithm that derives the complete location of each node in a network, without having to pass an initial position for each node?
- Is there a solid way to estimate the location of each point so that the algorithm can then correctly scale the distance between them? I have no geographic location of each of these nodes, that is the whole point of this exercise.
- Are there any algorithms to keep the 'angle' at which the network is derived constant between runs?

If all else fails, my next option is going to be to use the algorithm I mentioned above, increase the number of iterations to keep the variability between runs at around a few pixels (I'd have to experiment with how many iterations that would take), then 'rotate' each node around node 0 to, for example, align nodes 0 and 1 on a horizontal line from left to right; that way, I would 'correct' the location of the points after their relative distances have been determined by the MDS algorithm. I would have to correct for the order of connected nodes (clockwise or counterclockwise) around each node as well. This might become hairy quite quickly.

Obviously I'd prefer a stable algorithmic solution - increasing iterations to smooth out the randomness is not very reliable.

Thanks.

EDIT: I was referred to cs.stackexchange.com and some comments have been made there; for algorithmic suggestions, please see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18439/stable-multi-dimensional-scaling-algorithm .

Image 1 - with random initialization matrix:

[image: Image 1 - with random initialization matrix]

Image 2 - after running with same input data, rotated when compared to 1:

[image: Image 2 - after running with same input data, rotated when compared to 1]

Image 3 - same as previous 2, but nodes 1-3 are in another direction:

[image: Image 3 - same as previous 2, but nodes 1-3 are in another direction]

Image 4 - with the initial layout of the nodes on one line, their position on the y axis isn't changed:

[image: Image 4 - with the initial layout of the nodes on one line, their position on the y axis isn't changed]

Comment: After further developing my test data sets, I found out I have another requirement. I do not have distances between all nodes - nodes at one side of the network might be out of reach from nodes at the other side. I need a way to be able to specify this, without having to specify a biggish distance between those that are out of each others reach, because then the distance between those would be the same in the result graph. Preferably I'd like the nodes that are out of reach to be far away from each other, but maybe the visual would be clear too if I just didn't draw connections between them.

Comment: you can add a fake distance to separate unconnected groups (you may know this but what you want are the "simply connected components" in the graph), but each group can be individually reflected and rotated, unfortunately.  i deleted my answer as it just duplicated the idea you already had.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that term, I will investigate in that direction. Re: the other answer, OK clear - I was just checking if I was missing a detail. The information I can find on this topic is a lot more dense than much of my normal work, I need to double- and triple check often :) Thanks again for getting involved with this niche question - I couldn't even find any tags where it really belongs under.

Comment: no problem.  these kinds of questions are most interesting, they're just increasingly rare...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most scaling algorithms effectively set "springs" between nodes, where the resting length of the spring is the desired length of the edge. They then attempt to minimize the energy of the system of springs. When you initialize all the nodes on top of each other though, the amount of energy released when any one node is moved is the same in every direction. So the gradient of energy with respect to each node's position is zero, so the algorithm leaves the node where it is. Similarly if you start them all in a straight line, the gradient is always along that line, so the nodes are only ever moved along it.

(That's a flawed explanation in many respects, but it works for an intuition)

Try initializing the nodes to lie on the unit circle, on a grid or in any other fashion such that they aren't all co-linear. Assuming the library algorithm's update scheme is deterministic, that should give you reproducible visualizations and avoid degeneracy conditions.

If the library is non-deterministic, either find another library which is deterministic, or open up the source code and replace the randomness generator with a PRNG initialized with a fixed seed. I'd recommend the former option though, as other, more advanced libraries should allow you to set edges you want to "ignore" too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since asking this question, my research has led me to believe that MDS is not the right approach for my problem. (I was going to update the question as soon as I have confirmed this by having a working alternative...) There might be  terminology issue here, but what you are describing is, as far as I can tell, not an MDS algorithm but a graph layout algorithm. Which is what I'm going to use, mostly based on this paper: https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~tmm/courses/533/morereadings/dejordy.pdf . Boost.Graph has an implementation of several spring-based graph layout algos.

Comment: (Silly comment length restriction...) One fundamental property of (what is described in the literature I've read as) MDS algorithms is that they require a complete distance matrix, i.e. there needs to be an attraction or repulsion between each of the nodes. Whereas graph algorithms, like spring-based ones, don't need this. So thanks for your answer - it is what I'm going to try. As I mentioned, I will update this question with what my final results will be, as soon as I've validated that by having an actual implementation.

Comment: Yeah, MDS algorithms are different from graph layout ones (and I was wondering why you weren't using the latter, but figured you'd have your reasons), but many/most MDS algorithms sum some sort of cost function between every pair of nodes and then use a downhill optimization technique to minimize the sum's value. In that context the spring metaphor I described is still a nice, physical analogy that explains the problem with collinear starting positions, even if it isn't the basis for the algorithm like it is in force-directed graph drawing. Anyway, good luck with the implementation!

Comment: OK I think your comment went over my head the first few times I read it before replying. Your new comment made it click, I think. Thanks for bringing the two together - indeed I now understand why I was seeing the behavior I saw when all nodes started on one line. Given this mental model, indeed it should be possible to 'ignore' edges as you say, although that still won't give me the behavior that nodes at the 'edge' of networks will be placed away from each other like I understand e.g. Kamada/Kawai will, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, a MDS algorithm would happily display say a tree with all its points co-linear, unless you added faux springs to force children apart. Algorithms explicitly for graph drawing shouldn't have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the codes of the "SimpleMatrix" MDS library and found that it use a random permutation matrix to decide the order of points. After fix the permutation order (just use srand(12345) instead of srand(time(0))), the result of the same data is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there's no exact solution in general to this problem; with just 4 nodes `ABCD` and distances `AB=BC=AC=AD=BD=1` `CD=10` you cannot clearly draw a suitable 2D diagram (and not even a 3D one).

What those algorithms do is just placing springs between the nodes and then simulate a repulsion/attraction (depending on if the spring is shorter or longer than prescribed distance) probably also adding spatial friction to avoid resonance and explosion.

To keep a "stable" diagram just build a solution and then only update the distances, re-using the current position from previous solution as starting point. Picking two fixed nodes and aligning them seems a good idea to prevent a slow drift but I'd say that spring forces never end up creating a rotational momentum and thus I'd expect that just scaling and centering the solution should be enough anyway.